# generate foreign key for db model during create EDM in .net 3.5

Tags: linq, .net-3.5, foreign-keys, ado.net-entity-data-model

In my project I use .NET 3.5 and in this version during  generation Entity Data Model generation Foreign key option is disabled. Is it possible to do this without change the framework for example type myself in EDM.Designer.Cs file code which handles the use of Foreign Key?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, EF 3.5 doesn't yet support the foreign key columns in your entities - that's a new feature in EF 4.0 (.NET 4.0).

So basically the only available solution: switch to .NET 4.0 and you'll be fine - there's no other way to achieve this...